# uploadify upload

Tags: uploadify

There is a problem when I want to upload a picture, It does not upload pictures more than 3 MB, I located php.ini files and changed all the needed variables as needed, there is another ajax file upload script on my page right now, It works normal, uploads up to 40 MB, so the problem is not my php.ini for sure, are there any flash configurations that I should change ? and I placed fileSizeLimit 10 mb in my script, thank you :)

```
<?php $timestamp = time();?>
    $(function() {
        $('#file_upload').uploadify({
            'formData'     : {
                'timestamp' : '<?php echo $timestamp;?>',
                'token'     : '<?php echo md5('unique_salt' . $timestamp);?>'
            },
            'swf'      : 'uploadify.swf',
            'uploader' : 'uploadify.php',
            'sizeLimit'   : 10120*10120
        });
    });
```

Comment: Does the web server throw any sort of HTTP error?  What's the HTTP response?  Or is the HTTP request never even getting to the web server?

Comment: no, It is doing good until 3mb, no error, I don't know what is the problem

Comment: Maybe run it with [Fiddler](http://www.fiddler2.com) and post the full HTTP request and full HTTP response.  I have a hard time believing it uploads 3MB then just closes the socket and does absolutely nothing.

Comment: I am on linux, there is no linux version of fiddler, I asked uploadify's forum too, I hope they answer, thank you :)